# Mysql query group by 2 million records takes 7 seconds

Tags: mysql, performance

I had a query with group by condition takes 7 seconds. I had optimized all its data type and also given index.

Before index Execution time: 15 sec
After index and optimize data type its taken time: 7 seconds.

My database is much larger and I have to run approx 15 queries to prepare my report
the single query takes 7 sec then 15*7 = 105 sec it's too much time-consuming.

Sample Query:

```
Select 
    ca_id, 
    count(ca_id),
    email,
    cadate
from
    tbl_zonec
group by 
    email, 
    cadate,
    ca_id
```

Is there any way to optimize the query performance?

Comment: Are you using ORDER BY NULL ? Posting your sample query and sample data here would be useful

Comment: @PraveenE  Sample Query => Select id, count(ca_id),email,sample,cadate, from tbl_zonec , group by email, cadate,ca_id

Comment: try with ORDER BY NULL

Comment: Post your query, your sample data, result of your MySQL EXPLAIN command in the question. Will be useful for others.

Answer (score 1):

- Get rid of `id`; it is just plain wrong not to have it in the `GROUP BY`.  Ditto for `sample`.
- If `ca_id` cannot be `NULL`, say `COUNT(*)`.
- You seem to be scanning the entire table every time.  Do you get different results?  Is the table being added to?  Is old data being modified or deleted, or is this effectively a write-once table?  If the latter, then consider building and maintaining a [*Summary table*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables); it will be a lot faster.  (Perhaps 10-fold.)
- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  What is the `PRIMARY KEY`?  If it is does not *start with* `email, cadate, ca_id`, then there is an improvement possible.
- Without changing the PK, this would run a little faster:  `INDEX(email, cadate, ca_id, sample, id)` -- it is optimal for the `GROUP BY` and it is "covering".